# React-Native: The first DatePicker item always moved by 3 rows unintentionally when it got interaction

Tags: react-native, expo

Each Item of DatePicker should work independently. The problem is when I touch on DatePicker, the first item always moved by 3 rows including dragging on other items. Dragging on the first item has no issue.

[image]

I use DatePickerIOS from react-native, got the problem.
I use DatePicker from react-native-datepicker, still got the problem. I can't figure out why this happened.

This is my code for DatePicker. This is just default code without any modification though.

```js
    <DatePickerIOS
      mode={this.props.mode}
      date={this.props.date}
      onDateChange={this.props.onDateChange}
      minuteInterval={this.props.minuteInterval}
      locale="th"
    />
```

Comment: What are the values of the prop variables you are passing in? I'd specifically like to know what you onDateChange method does.

Comment: I didn't pass any value to onDateChange.

Comment: So this.props.onDateChange is null? In the official expo documentation (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/datepickerios/) you will see that they have a method to handle the state change. I'd suggest starting there, and seeing what the value of the date object that is being passed into that method is. I'm not sure what behaviour would occur if that onChange method is null (or even if it can be), but its a good place to start.

Comment: I've ignored it and do another page instead until now. I'm going back to check it again. The problem is gone without doing anything. It's weird.